# Python request not retrieving data from API, when the URLhas Japanese characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using python3.7 and running my code in Unix environment.

In my code, I have to hit some api and retrieve the data in json format, however when my source data has the japenese or non ascii characters, then it is not able to get the data form the request. Same api call when i make through the postman, it is returning me data.

Do i need to make any encoding changes if i have non -ascii characters in the api request?

```
bash-4.2$ more sourcefile.csv
"ひとみ","Abràmoff","70141558"
```

```
import requests
import csv

with open('sourcefile.csv', "r" ) as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for lines in csv_reader:
        FRST_NM = (lines[0])
        LST_NM = (lines[1])
        ID = (lines[2])

URL2 ='<base url>?filter=(equals(FirstName,"' + FRST_NM + '"))and(equals(LastName,"' + LST_NM + '"))and(equals(ID,"' + ID + '"))'



full_data = requests.get(URL2)


print(full_data.json())
```

This is returning `[]`, however it should return the data.

Comment: As an aside, using `+` to concatenate strings is generally not necessary in Python and not generally very "pythonic".  Since you are using Python 3.7 you can use [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) like `url  = f'?filter=(equals(FirstName,"{FRST_NM}"))and(equals(LastName,"{LST_NM}"))` and so on.

Comment: What does the API documentation say about what it expects for non-ASCII characters? What is the encoding of the CSV file? Does `URL2` look correct if you display it before attempting the request?

Comment: When you pass this URL through requests, it processes it through a function called `requests.utils.requote_uri` which converts it to something looking like: `?filter=(equals(FirstName,%22%E3%81%B2%E3%81%A8%E3%81%BF%22))` and so on, where the `%HH` are hexadecimal encoding of the UTF-8 encoding of the string.  It's possible the API you're using does not handle this properly, or is expecting a different encoding from UTF-8.

Comment: When I am printing the URL, it is displaying the correct URL, and also same URL when I hit using postman, it is retrieving the data.

Answer (score -2):

You can use BeautifulSoup https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-beautifulsoup/ 
from that you can extract the information .